# Correct way to subscribe and update URL query variables in Angular?

Tags: angular, url-routing

I have an Angular application with a multi-selection menu (Component A), which determines the data displayed in a second component (Component B). Initially they communicated directly, but when the time came to add query variables to the application URL (to enable bookmarking), I began getting 'value changed after it was checked errors'.

To fix this, I implemented the approach in the diagram below.

- The selection component (A) adds IDs to the URL and subscribes to any changes in the URL, so it is accurate if the user returns to a bookmarked link
- The display component (B) also subscribes to changes in the URL and retrieves data from an API when the user IDs in the URL change.

This works and is error free, but it feels convoluted that communication between the components is 'via' the URL.

Are there any drawbacks / criticisms with this approach and is there a better alternative, e.g. [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345683/whats-the-correct-way-to-update-model-and-url)?

[image]

Comment: You could subscribe directly to selection componet to get selected items. Other that that its fine+-